# What is the technical word associated to the binary representation of types?

Tags: c++, programming-languages, terminology, endianness

I am currently writing a function that tests endianness and `sizeof()` fundamental types in C++ in order to dectect if the system/compiler is "classic" or non-standard. I search a name for this function, like `checkSystemSOMETHING()` but I don't know the word associated to things like binary representation of types or endianness. What would be the best word to replace `SOMETHING` ?

Comment: Your own suggestion is good: `checkSystemEndianAndSizeof()`

Comment: I think I'd use checkSystemArchitecture.

Comment: Note C++ only talks about *object representation* and *value representation*; I don't think it assigns a word to what defines the sizes of integer types or their layout in memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is "data model".  Relevant again after the long stability of 32-bit computing, different choices were made in 64-bit architectures.  Windows is LLP64, Linux is LP64.  Reference [is here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).